Disable motion sensor for a ceiling lamp
I recently moved in to a new rented apartment (Netherlands) and there is a motion controlled ceiling lamp in the entrance hall which is highly annoying as it triggers off slightest movement.
Here is the lamp setup itself:

And this is the sensor I identified here - Merrytek MC070S:

As far as I can see, the sensor has no setting to be turned off permanently. And I would want either this, or disable the lamp completely. Since this is a rented apartment and I do not feel overly comfortable dealing with electricity past basic stuff, I would rather avoid any intrusive solutions.
Do you guys have an idea what could I do to disable the sensor or just powert off the lamp? (if the latter, how would I do it cleanly so it does not short accidentally)
Thanks in advance

Location might matter, but code requires a room light to come on either by a switch near the doorway or some other way, when a person(fire, police, EMTs, prevent you from stepping on legos) enters.

@crip659 Europe, Netherlands -- added to the question. I wish so badly it was a simple switch

The Merrytek device is a "microwave motion sensor" according to its data sheet https://www.otec.com.ua/show_catalogue_pdf/186206/1 It does not have a complete motion sense disable. But it transmits at 5.8GHz. Perhaps absorbing that frequency of radio waves with an electrically-insulated substance (if such exists) placed over the Merrytek.

Have you tried swiching DIP switch #1 to OFF?  Based on the pic it may reduce the sensitivity.

@Huesmann it's already in the OFF position :/ I studied all the switches and found no obvious way to make it any less different except maybe turn daylight sensor on to prevent some daylight triggers

Worst case, you could mask the led strips with (removable on termination of your lease) cardboard.

Is it just a motion sensor or motion+light? If it's just motion, you  should just be able to put a tape on the sensor. Probably that tiny black circle.

I am not entirely sure... I taped the black circle, still seems to work in the same way.

Sorry for the late reply. A couple of things. Tape the whole box (if you haven't tried this already). I'm having trouble to find the manual for this particular unit. But it's possible that the sensor is somewhere else. Take a look at the image below. Good luck. https://i.imgur.com/JCjtgb1.png

You can't tamper with the electricdls in a rental, in most of the world.
I can't quite read the label in this photo, but there may be some combination of those DIP switches which does roughly what you want.
